# How to check list of running software using systeminformation or others process manage npm library?

Tags: node.js, process, system-information

When running the system, I want to know the background running the software list. The software will be must application software not system software.

How can I know this using `systeminformation` library or any other Node js process handling library? Is this possible or not?

Please help.